# Fastest algorithm to test for 75%+ similarity of 2 strings?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I need a function that takes in 2 strings and returns a boolean if they are more than 75% similar.
Levenshtein works, but I find it WAY too slow for the amount of data that I am processing.

If I can somehow determine the 75%+ similar first, I can then run the Levenshtein for the exact similarity match.

**EDIT**

Here are some examples of what I mean by similarity:

```
isSimilar75("texts", "txts") //TRUE, 85% similar
isSimilar75("hello world", "hello word") //TRUE, 91% similar
isSimilar75("this is an example of longer text", "this is an example of a longer txt") //TRUE, 92% similar
isSimilar75("this is a test", "test what") //FALSE, 29% similar
```

The function calculates similarity similar to levenshtein. I simply need a more simple version of levenshtein that only returns whether or not a string is "around" 75% similar based on the amount of character operations (add, subtract, and substitute characters). The function does not need to return a percentage or do any exact calculations, I will only run the expensive levenshtein on results that return true from this function.

Comment: *Define* 75% similar.

Comment: @superbrain I added more details

Comment: Ref [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) may help.

Answer (score 1):

The Levenshtein distance between two words is lowerbounded by the L1 distance between their frequency vectors. So we could do something like

```
import collections
def possiblySimilar75(s1, s2):
    c1 = collections.Counter(s1)
    c2 = collections.Counter(s2)
    return sum(abs(c1[x] - c2[x]) for x in set(c1.keys()) | set(c2.keys())) <= max(len(s1), len(s2)) / 4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a linear loop that compares two sorted strings using counters for

1. the first string index, `ai`
2. the second string index, `bi`
3. the `same` characters
4. the `not` same characters

```js
function strDiff(a = "", b = "")
{ const _a =
    [...a.toLowerCase()].sort()
    
  const _b =
    [...b.toLowerCase()].sort()

  const loop = (same, not, ai, bi) =>
  ai > a.length && bi > b.length
      ? same / (same + not)
  : ai > a.length || bi > b.length 
      ? loop(same, not + 1, ai + 1, bi + 1)
  : _a[ai] < _b[bi]
      ? loop(same, not + 1, ai + 1, bi)
  : _a[ai] > _b[bi]
      ? loop(same, not + 1, ai, bi + 1)
  : loop(same + 1, not, ai + 1, bi + 1)
  
  return loop(0, 0, 0, 0)
}
  
console.log(strDiff("fooBar", "floBro")) // 0.75
```

It works like this -

```
strDiff("fooBar", "floBro")
// ...

_a = abfoor 
_b = bfloor

//   same  not  ai  bi    _a[ai]     _b[bi] 
loop(0,    0,   0,  0) // "a"        "b"
loop(0,    1,   1,  0) // "b"        "b"
loop(1,    1,   2,  1) // "f"        "f"
loop(2,    1,   3,  2) // "o"        "l"
loop(2,    2,   3,  3) // "o"        "o"
loop(3,    2,   4,  4) // "o"        "o"
loop(4,    2,   5,  5) // "r"        "r"
loop(5,    2,   6,  6) // undefined  undefined
loop(6,    2,   7,  7) // undefined  undefined
6 / (6 + 2)            // same / (same + not)
0.75                   // <- output
```